# Pythonic way of designing functions within a module

Tags: python

When designing a module is it a better practice to have multiple functions that perform similar operations or one function which behaves differently based on an argument.

```py
def to_hex(val):
    pad = bits // 4
    return '{:X}'.format(val).zfill(pad)

def to_bin(val):
    pad = bits
    return '{:b}'.format(val).zfill(pad)
...
```

Or:

```py
def to_string(val, form='b'):
    if form == 'X':
        pad = bits // 4
    elif form == 'o':
        ...

    return '{:{form}}'.format(val, form=form).zfill(pad)
```

This may be opinion based but what is the pythonic approach?

Comment: both versions are "pythonic", so it just comes down to style and what you prefer, if you go with the first option maybe nice to have in a class structure versus the second one which can just be a stand alone, with a class you can access several attributes if this program becomes huge, hope that helps :)

Comment: Is this the all code? are you accepting user input here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of them are okay. However, in the second case, if there are too many control flows embedded into your procedural code, that might obfuscate your intent to the reader. Use the first approach to avoid too many `if else` logic. But if your methods are very similar, you should encapsulate them within a class. This approach will help you avoid unnecessary repetition. For example:

```py
class HexBin:
    def __init__(self, val, bits):
        self.val = val
        self.bits = bits

    def to_hex(self):
        pad = self.bits // 4
        return '{:X}'.format(self.val).zfill(pad)

    def to_bin(self):
        pad = self.bits
        return '{:b}'.format(self.val).zfill(pad)
```

You can use it like this:

```py
>> obj = HexBin(10, 10)

>> print(obj.to_hex())
>> print(obj.to_bin())
```

```
0A
0000001010
```